# Azure Active Directory Single-Page application infrastructure

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

I am trying to connect my frontend and backend applications to Azure Active Directory. There are different tutorials how to achieve that. Some of them explain that I need to register two separate applications in Azure and some are showing implementation with only one. I am wondering which is the correct way? Can't I have one application in Azure and login the user on the frontend and then use the same credentials to verify the token that is passed? I am using .NET Core 3.1 and couldn't make it work neither with one nor with two separate application in Azure. I have some experience with AWS Cognito and there I could handle all the logic on the server so that I don't have to expose any client IDs or credentials but looks like I will need a different approach with Azure AD. Any suggestions how to handle this situation or working implementation examples will be appreciated because I have been struggling with that for the past two days.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: Still can't make it work :(

Comment: Did you encounter any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is signing users to your frontend webapp, and then calling web APIs（backend app） on behalf of the signed-in user. Just like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview). It is recommended that you register two applications, one for fronend app, the other one for backend app. Here is a [complete sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg) for your reference.